# IntelliJ doesn't recognize TypeTag in Scala

Tags: java, scala, gradle, intellij-idea, reflection

I'm trying to compile these 2 lines of code in **Scala** (using Gradle):

```scala
import import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
val typeInt = typeTag[Int]
```

It turns out somehow that IntelliJ mark the word `runtime` with the color red. and throw me this error: `object runtime is not a member of package reflect one error found`

Now, the weird thing for me, is when I'm using the Scala REPL, it finds this package **without any issue**.

```scala
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> val typeInt = typeTag[Int]
val typeInt: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Int] = TypeTag[Int]
```

---

### Gradle's `build.gradle` file

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'scala'
    id 'com.github.maiflai.scalatest' version '0.26'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.13:2.9.9'
    implementation 'com.typesafe:config:1.4.0'
    testCompile 'org.scalamock:scalamock_2.13:4.4.0'
    testCompile 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.13:3.1.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-all:0.35.10'
}
```

---

### Versions

- **IntelliJ IDEA - Community** - Version 2020.2.3
- **JDK** - Version 14.0.1
- **macOS Catalina** - Version 10.15.7
- **Scala** - Version 2.13.3
- **Gradle** - Version 6.7

Comment: the double `import` in your first code line is a typo, right?

Comment: Feedback from the REPL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your `build.gradle` you didn't add `scala-reflect` dependency

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.13.3

`scala-library` is not enough if you want to use Scala reflection.

Try to add `scala-reflect`

```
implementation 'org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.13.3'
```